# Rust: Passing borrowed struct to a borrowed enum?

Tags: enums, rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to pass a borrowed struct into a borrowed enum.

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct CustomerData {
    // Many fields about customers
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct EmployeeData {
    // Many fields about employees
}

pub enum Person {
    Customer(CustomerData),
    Employee(EmployeeData)
}

fn do_something_with_customer(customer: &CustomerData) {
    let person = &Person::Customer(customer);

    // This would work, but this can be a large struct.
    // let person = &Person::Customer(customer.clone());

    general_method(person);
}

fn do_something_with_employee(employee: &EmployeeData) {
    let person = &Person::Employee(employee);

    // This would work, but this can be a large struct.
    // let person = &Person::Employee(employee.clone());

    general_method(person);
}

fn general_method(person: &Person) {

}

fn main() {
    let person = Person::Customer(CustomerData { });

    match &person {
        Person::Customer(data) => {
            do_something_with_customer(data);
        }
        Person::Employee(data) => {
            do_something_with_employee(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling gives me the result:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:36
   |
19 |     let person = &Person::Customer(customer);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^
   |                                    |
   |                                    expected struct `CustomerData`, found reference
   |                                    help: consider dereferencing the borrow: `*customer`
   |
   = note: expected type `CustomerData`
              found type `&CustomerData`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:28:36
   |
28 |     let person = &Person::Employee(employee);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^
   |                                    |
   |                                    expected struct `EmployeeData`, found reference
   |                                    help: consider dereferencing the borrow: `*employee`
   |
   = note: expected type `EmployeeData`
              found type `&EmployeeData`
```

I get that the Rust compiler isn't allowing me to do this, but I feel like I should be able to, considering the enum I'm passing my structs to is borrowed as well.

Is there a pattern/workaround for this scenario? Maybe using the `Rc` type? I'd hate to litter my code with it for this scenario.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct CustomerData {
    // Many fields about customers
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct EmployeeData {
    // Many fields about employees
}

pub enum Person {
    Customer(Rc<CustomerData>),
    Employee(Rc<EmployeeData>)
}

fn do_something_with_customer(customer: Rc<CustomerData>) {
    let person = &Person::Customer(customer);

    // This would work, but this can be a large struct.
    // let person = &Person::Customer(customer.clone());

    general_method(person);
}

fn do_something_with_employee(employee: Rc<EmployeeData>) {
    let person = &Person::Employee(employee);

    // This would work, but this can be a large struct.
    // let person = &Person::Employee(employee.clone());

    general_method(person);
}

fn general_method(person: &Person) {

}

fn main() {
    let person = Person::Customer(Rc::new(CustomerData { }));

    match &person {
        Person::Customer(data) => {
            do_something_with_customer(data.clone());
        }
        Person::Employee(data) => {
            do_something_with_employee(data.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misidentified the problem and the compiler was spot-on on its error comments.

You defined your enum like so:

```
pub enum Person {
    Customer(CustomerData),
    Employee(EmployeeData)
}
```

But then you decide that your enum member should be `Person::Customer(&CustomerData)`:

```
fn do_something_with_customer(customer: &CustomerData) {
    let person = &Person::Customer(customer);
```

References are not transitive. Because `&CustomerData` is a reference does not mean that the entire enum will be a reference to real data (i.e. `&Person::Customer(CustomerData)`).

There are two ways to fix it; the obvious is to see if `CustomerData` implements `Copy`. If it does, you can just dereference (and therefore implicitly copy):

```
fn do_something_with_customer(customer: &CustomerData) {
    let person = Person::Customer(*customer);
```

(This is what the compiler suggested, so I'm pretty sure your type implements `Copy`)

The other option is to `#[derive(Clone)]` on the type and call `customer.clone()`. Again, at the cost of an extra allocation.

If you really want the reference in the enum, you need to change the enum definition to:

```
pub enum Person<'a> {
    Customer(&'a CustomerData),
    Employee(&'a EmployeeData)
}
```

And handle the fact that the object property is now a reference, with all the problems associated.

Comment: The compiler may complain, but in theory, what I was trying to do *should be safe*. Also, copy is not an option, because my structs are very large. I was hoping to avoid lifetime identifiers, so I think ```Rc``` will be my option.

Comment: Also, I noticed that I can automatically borrow the enum data when I ```match &value```, so I figured the same thing could have been done vice versa.

Comment: This one isn't about the safety of *this*, but the safety of *what can come afterwards*. If you duplicate the struct (via `Rc` or `Copy` or `Clone`) you effectively have two independent entities in memory (`Rc` is a special case), all of them immutable. What if you then want to mutate this data?

Comment: In the case of `Copy` or `Clone`, you can, but you won't touch the other structs. In the case of `Rc` you cannot, **period**, and you then need to wrap this `Rc` around `RefCell` to have interior mutability

Comment: The crux of this is down to what you actually want to achieve overall. Do you just want an immutable copy of the data, even when the enum is owned? `Rc`. Do you want to pass a reference around and can guarantee your object lifetime restrictions fit? `&`. Is your case the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)? `Copy`/`Clone` is fine.

Comment: Also, there is no real reason to be afraid of references. If you write your code in a sane fashion you only really see the definitions of them on the definition of structs, traits and enums; in actual business logic, most of them get elided and/or simplified by the compiler. The real crux of this is really that there are three solutions to solve your problem, and they all depend with what you do with your data **after** the snippet you showed us :-)

Comment: I'd never want to mutate these values. The names I gave in the example imply they may change (customer name, etc). However, in my actual scenario, these enums describe events that don't change.

Comment: I'm new to rust (obviously), but my enums may be contained within error types, and I don't think error types should have lifetime identifiers.

Comment: That rules out references in 99% of cases. Since you mentioned yourself that `Clone`/`Copy` isn't an option due to size, this means you answered your own question with `Rc` :-) Do note as well that `Rc::new()` calls aren't actually necessary. `Rc<T>` implements [`From<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#1162-1166), which means that wherever you need a `Rc<T>` you can simply call `into()`